# Meteor.call returns undefined when returned from _.wrapAsync function

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, redis

When the template view is loaded, the client does a `Meteor.call('getPlayerScore')` to the server to grab some data.

On the server, the method `getPlayerScore` executes a synchronous function `client.zrevrangeSync` using `_.wrapAsync` and returns `1234` string after the wrapped function finishes running.

**Problem:** Why does the client receive `result` as `undefined`? `result` is not undefined if it is returned before `client.zrevrangeSync` is called, but is undefined if returned from within `client.zrevrangeSync`.

```
Meteor.methods({

    getPlayerScore: function(playerId) {

        var client = redis.createClient(6379, redisServer)

        client.zrevrangeSync = Meteor._wrapAsync(client.zrevrange)
        client.zrevrangeSync(['players:' + playerId, 0, 3, 'WITHSCORES'], function(err, result) {
            return '1234'
        })
    }

})





Template.playerScoreboard.helpers({
    playerScore: function () {

        Meteor.call('getPlayerScore', 1, function (error, result) { 
            console.log('result: ', result)
            return
        });

    }
})
```

Comment: I am not 100% how the `_wrapAsync` routine works exactly, but doesn't the method itself need to return something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically you don't give a callback in & return what you get/unless its coffee script.

```
client.zrevrangeSync = Meteor._wrapAsync(client.zrevrange.bind(client));

return client.zrevrangeSync(['players:' + playerId, 0, 3, 'WITHSCORES']);
```

Comment: Can you clarify what it means by giving a callback in? Btw what does `.bind()` do? I omitted that and it still works perfect!

Comment: bind makes sure that the context of client binds correcly with client.zrevrange. Sometimes its an issue, particularly if the method is more nested. The callback was the `function(error, result) {..}` which won't be able to return on a method because its async.